# The getter 'displayName' isn't defined for the type 'List<UserModal>'. But I have defined it. Is there something I am doing wrong?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-provider

My userModel class

```
class UserModal {
String? userId;
String? email;
String? imageUrl;
String? displayName;
String? gender;
String? age;
String? phoneNumber;

UserModal({
required this.userId,
required this.email,
this.displayName,
this.imageUrl,
this.age,
this.gender,
this.phoneNumber,
});

Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
return {
  'userId': userId,
  'email': email,
  'imageUrl': imageUrl,
  'displayName': displayName,
  'gender': gender,
  'age': age,
  'phoneNumber': phoneNumber,
  };
 }
}
```

My code on the Firebase Service side

```
List<UserModal> _getUserModalFromSnapshot(QuerySnapshot snapshot) {
return snapshot.docs.map((doc) {
  return UserModal(
    userId: (doc.data() as dynamic)['userId'],
    email: (doc.data() as dynamic)['email'],
    imageUrl: (doc.data() as dynamic)['imageUrl'],
    displayName: (doc.data() as dynamic)['displayName'],
    gender: (doc.data() as dynamic)['gender'],
    age: (doc.data() as dynamic)['age'],
    phoneNumber: (doc.data() as dynamic)['phoneNumber'],
  );
}).toList();
}
  
Stream<List<UserModal>> get getUserModal => _usersCollection
  .snapshots()
  .map((snapshot) => _getUserModalFromSnapshot(snapshot));
```

Calling Stream Provider in main.dart

```
StreamProvider<List<UserModal>>(
        create: (context) => DatabaseService().getUserModal,
        initialData: []),
```

Using Provider in the UI

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
final userMod = Provider.of<List<UserModal>>(context);
userMod.forEach((element) {
  print(userMod.displayName);
});
```

Users collection has been created in firebase firestore and the values are stored in the fields. But stream is not getting fields name when calling it inside my UI. I am not able to understand what am I doing wrong?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d1ngT.png)

Comment: inside ```forEach``` loop you need to print ```element.displayName``` instead of ```userMod.displayName```

Comment: why u make userid and email field nullable if they are required

Comment: Pay attention to the error message: it's telling you that's you're trying to access a `displayName` property on a `List`, *not* on a `UserModel` object.

Answer (score 2):

In your code `userMod` is in the type of `List<UserModal>` which is basically a List class in dart.

What you have to do is :

```
userMod.forEach((element) {
  print(element.displayName);
});
```

And now you're looping over the userMod list and taking each `element` as objects of your `UserModal` class where the displayName is defined as a property.

Comment: Yes, that works! hehe thanks!